# Batch file run error in Windows 8.1

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-8.1

I have created a batch file to automatically do network configurations for home and work wifi.

Code is as follow:

---

```
netsh wlan connect name="Mahesh"

if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (

     echo "Home wifi Connected."

) else (
     netsh wlan connect name="Umiya- SecureWiFi"
     netsh interface ip set address name="Umiya- SecureWiFi" source=static addr=192.168.36.19 mask=255.255.0.0 gateway=192.168.36.1 gwmetric=1
     netsh interface ip set dns name="Umiya- SecureWiFi" source=static addr=202.131.104.2 primary
     netsh interface ip add dns name="Umiya- SecureWiFi" addr=202.131.104.3 index=2
     echo "Work wifi connected"
)
```

---

When I execute the script in cmd, i got the following **error for 2-4 lines in else condition**:

---

```
Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

---

How to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `ip` to `ipv4`, `dns` to `dnsservers` and `addr` to `address`:

```
netsh wlan connect name="Mahesh"

if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (

     echo "Home wifi Connected."

) else (
     netsh wlan connect name="Umiya- SecureWiFi"
     netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Umiya- SecureWiFi" source=static address=192.168.36.19 mask=255.255.0.0 gateway=192.168.36.1 gwmetric=1
     netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers name="Umiya- SecureWiFi" source=static address=202.131.104.2 primary
     netsh interface ipv4 add dnsservers name="Umiya- SecureWiFi" address=202.131.104.3 index=2
     echo "Work wifi connected"
)
```

`set dnsservers` usage:

```
Usage: set dnsservers [name=]<string> [source=]dhcp|static
             [[address=]<IP address>|none]
             [[register=]none|primary|both]
             [[validate=]yes|no]
```

`add dnsservers` usage:

```
Usage: add dnsservers [name=]<string> [address=]<IPv4 address>
             [[index=]<integer>] [[validate=]yes|no]
```

Comment: Hi Ofir, I tried with your modifications, but got the same error in same lines.

Comment: @KaranShah seems that they made more changes, I've edited my answer, can you check again?

Comment: Yes Ofir, I checked this and got some errors:
1) The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.(in ipv4 set address command).
2) 'Usage:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.(in both Usage commands).